# How to add schema/other user to database url given to java?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm trying to connect a spring boot java application to an Oracle database. Oracle SQL Developer shows the tables I wish to query being in the DB named `testdb` under Other users -> `testUser.

I can connect to the DB using url `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testdb`. However, when I use an SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_DEFINITION WHERE SCHEMA_NM = ?
```

Java doesn't find the table named SCHEMA_DEFINITION. Using `testUser.SCHEMA_DEFINITION` in the SQL statement does work. How can I tell Java to look for all the tables in `Other users->testUser`?

I have tried setting the datasource's schema (`dataSource.setSchema("testUser");`) and changing the url (adding `?search_path=testUser` and `?currentSchema=testUser`).

None of these work.

Comment: Found the solution in https://github.com/embulk/embulk-input-jdbc/issues/144. dataSource.setSchema("testUser"); works if I use ojdbc7 (I was using ojdbc6 in my pom.xml).

Answer (score 2):

it's not a java issue, what you need is to log into the user `testUser` so you can query those tables without the verbose syntax if you really need to keep these queries as is, and run them from `testdb` then you need to create synonyms for those tables inside `testdb` schema:

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM TESTDB.SCHEMA_DEFINITION FOR testUser.SCHEMA_DEFINITION;
```

do this for each table and they will work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in github.com/embulk/embulk-input-jdbc/issues/144. dataSource.setSchema("testUser"); works if I use ojdbc7 (I was using ojdbc6 in my pom.xml).